# Check if user and another user like each other and fetch the liking user's information

Tags: mysql, sql

this is my first question here, although I've been utilizing this site for years for help. Maybe it's because I'm sick but I can't figure something out.

I have two tables in a database `[User]` and `[Like]`

The `[User]` table has basic information like (`id`, `name`, `age`)...

The `[Like]` table simply stores which users like which `user` (`user`, `user`) ... So for example if `User A` likes `User B`, it stores it in the `[Like]` table as `user (A) likes user(B)`. With foreign key constraints.

I now need to fetch from the database, all users that like `User A`, that `User A` also likes back, including all their respective data from the `[User]` table.

Example...

```
[Like table]

user A -> user B

user B -> user A

user A -> user C

user C -> user B
```

Assuming the current user I'm checking for is `User A`, I need my query to return

```
(user B, user B's name, user B's age)
```

because both `User A` and `User B` like each other and thus, I need the info the `User B` only.

My Current MySQL statement goes:

```
SELECT li.like_id 
from `like` as li 
join `like` as ui 
     on li.like_id = ui.user_id 
where li.user_id = **USER_A** 
group by li.like_id;
```

which seemingly returns the people who like `User_A`... I can't figure out why because as I've mentioned earlier, I'm out of it... But I must to work... so work I shall... with help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select u.*
from
    `like` ul inner join `like` lu
        on ul.user_id = lu.like_id and ul.like_id = lu.user_id
    inner join `user` u
        on u.id = ul.like_id
where
    ul.user_id = ?
```

**EXPLANATION** They key is really in the join between the two instances of the like table. Ultimately it says match each "like" with another "like" that has the same user_id and like_id values except in the reverse order. Using an inner join rather than an outer join guarantees that the relationship is reciprocal so it throws away all the ones you aren't interested in.

At that point you're only interested in the "liked" user's attributes so the final step is look up the `ul.like_id` against the `user` table. (`lu.user_id` has to have the same value so it would work too.)

notevenwrong's answer is pretty much identical. It does have the disadvantage of using the `USER_A` parameter in two places although that could be eliminated in the subquery by correlating with the outer reference.

I think the join does kind of highlight the symmetrical nature of the query and is more adaptable to other uses. It's certainly possible that the `exists` version is faster though.

Comment: This works... I understand it slightly. Thank you. I would prefer to understand it even more. I'm rusty on Joins and such. If would care to elaborate on the reasoning behind the code, that would be very helpful. If not, thank you regardless. I changed the `Select ...` to `Select u.*` and it worked perfectly if anyone's concerned.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT l.like_id
FROM like as l
WHERE l.user_id=USER_A
AND EXISTS
  (SELECT l2.like_id
   FROM like as l2
   WHERE l2.like_id=USER_A
   AND l2.user_id=l.like_id);
```

Comment: This seems like a cleaner way to go about what I was doing earlier. I'm still stuck at the main problem, which is fetching all the corresponding users' data from the User table.